# MongoDB group aggregation of multiple elements and sub-documents

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and am trying to figure out how to group based on two elements, one of which is time and the other is a sub-document.  My data structure is based on the cube structure:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52d931f9f61313b46bf456b0"),
        "type" : "build",
        "time" : ISODate("2014-01-17T01:27:18.413Z"),
        "data" : {
                "build_number" : 7,
                "build_duration" : 885843,
                "build_url" : "job/Test_Job/7/",
                "build_project_name" : "Test_Job",
                "build_result" : "SUCCESS"
        }
}
```

I was able to get some Stackoverflow help grouping when my structure was flat, but I'm having trouble with the data sub-document.  Here is one of many query variations I have tried:

```
db.nb.aggregate(     
    {          
        $group: {              
            _id: {                 
                dayOfMonth: { $dayOfMonth: "$time" },
                build_project_name: { data: $build_project_name }  
            },
            build_duration: { $avg: data: { "$build_duration" } }                       
        },     
    } 
)
```

I've tried many different variations on the syntax, but can't seem to get it quite right.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pretty much you want to do this:

```
db.nb.aggregate(
[ 
    {$group: 
        {_id: 
            { dayOfMonth: { $dayOfMonth: "$time" }, 
            build_project_name: "$data.build_project_name" 
        }, 
        build_duration: { $avg: "$data.build_duration"  }} 
    }  
])
```

First, remember aggregate receives an array of operation for input:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{...},
{...}
])
```

Second, references to sub-documents are represented like a tree, so $data.buildduration points to node data "field" builduration inside of data.